# How do I delete form response of google form at runtime?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have two forms: form1 and form2

I have a condition that, after submission of form2, user has to submit form1. But if user submits form1 without submitting form2 then I want to delete it's response at the same moment as I don't want that entry in my spreadsheet. How do I prevent user from submitting a form or is there a way to delete response at runtime so there would be no any entry of that submission?

Comment: Take a look at [onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3). As you've shared no code, we cannot really help you here.

Comment: You can't delete individual responses in the Form using code.  You can delete all of the responses using code, but not just one response.  If what you want is to delete the response in the spreadsheet, then you need to find the row that was just saved.  You could delete the last found row in the spreadsheet, but if you have multiple users simultaneously submitting a Form in rapid succession, then there could be a problem with deleting the wrong row.  You need an On Form Submit function in the spreadsheet.  Get the values and compare them to the last row, if they match, then delete that row.

Comment: However, there is another problem, because what if two people submitted exactly the same data.  So, you might want to collect the users email address and compare the email address to make sure that you are deleting the correct row.

Comment: Thank you @SandyGood . When multiple users will submit form at once and if two users submitted form concurrently then there would be a problem of which record I should delete. Exactly I found same solution that you stated above, if I use getActiveUser() method, then that method can distinguish two users and rows and I can easily delete that particular row. But there are possibilities that if user fills form via incognito mode or if user fills form from other browser like Mozilla, UC Browser or Opera then?

Comment: @Casper It's not possible for me to upload code. It's very big code. Two modules are very big so I can't upload code.

Comment: You can use LockService to prevent two instances of the code running simultaneously.

Comment: @SandyGood Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I'll try it. I just read 3 lines of description in Google's app script documentation and realized this was main purpose of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can now delete a single form item response: see here.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteallresponses
deleteResponse(responseId)
Deletes a single response from the form's response store. This method does not delete copies of responses stored in an external response destination (like a spreadsheet), but does remove the response from the form's summary view. The response ID can be retrieved with FormResponse.getId().